# Renaming a dict key to value of other key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm kinda new to python but I have a dict containing sort of key pairs:

```
{
   "ata_smart_attributes_table_0_name":"Raw_Read_Error_Rate",
   "ata_smart_attributes_table_0_raw_value":0,
   "ata_smart_attributes_table_7_name":"Power_On_Hours",
   "ata_smart_attributes_table_7_raw_value":1046,
}
```

I want to rename the '..0_name' key to the value of that key. 
And at the same time the '..0_raw_value' value, has to become the value of the '..0_name' key like so:

```
{
   "Raw_Read_Error_Rate":0,
   "Power_On_Hours":1046,
}
```

I've been breaking my head over this, any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean interchange value and key ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the desired result.

Comment: I've added the desired result, sorry for in completion.

Comment: Does this need to work for any combination of name and raw value? I.E not just hardcodeing the dict for these specific values

Comment: Yes it does, I have a dict to around 40 key total,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    "ata_smart_attributes_table_0_name": "Raw_Read_Error_Rate",
    "ata_smart_attributes_table_0_raw_value": 0,
    "ata_smart_attributes_table_7_name": "Power_On_Hours",
    "ata_smart_attributes_table_7_raw_value": 1046,
}

out = {
    v: dct[k.rsplit("_", maxsplit=1)[0] + "_raw_value"]
    for k, v in dct.items()
    if k.endswith("_name")
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{"Raw_Read_Error_Rate": 0, "Power_On_Hours": 1046}
```

Comment: Super succient.